# Is there an "LFD" key on my keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, emacs, key-binding

Emacs uses keybindings with "LFD", the [Emacs FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-faq) provides the following information:

> LFD: Linefeed or Newline; same as `C-j'

Is there a `Linefeed` button on my keyboard (other than `C-j`)?

Answer (score 3):

Don't think so. In your keyboard, probably, you have only the "return", "enter" key. There's no linefeed in regular IBM-PC keyboard.

In windows you can use the Shift + Enter to mean a linefeed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646268%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I figured out that `Shift + Enter` replaces `C-x LFD` for the emacs keybinding in question.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently some keyboards do have an LFD key, because the BASH docs also mention this:

```
If your keyboard lacks a LFD key, typing C-j will produce the desired character.
```

http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_82.html

Comment: commodore 128 seens to be the only keyboard with a linefeed key